# Model definition for a ParametricNDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, fitting

I have the following code

```
    params = {a,b};
    ss = ParametricNDSolve[{EQ\[Phi]2, EQr2, EQ\[Theta]2, r[0] == 232.5, 
    r'[0] == -0.105, \[Phi][0] == 
    0, \[Phi]'[0] == -0.089 r'[0], \[Theta][0] == 
    Pi/2, \[Theta]'[0] == 0.1 \[Phi]'[0]}, {\[Phi], 
    r, \[Theta]}, {\[Tau], 39.3 86, 40.4 86}, params, 
    Method -> {StiffnessSwitching, 
    Method -> {ExplicitRungeKutta, Automatic}}, AccuracyGoal -> 15, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 16, MaxSteps -> Infinity];
```

I would like to create a model to use FindFit with some data.

```
    fit = FindFit[data, model[Sequence @@ params][x], params, x, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 4, AccuracyGoal -> 4]
```

But the model is not given by  phi, r and theta coming from ParametricNDSolve; the model is defined by

```
    x=rr[tt] Sin[\[Theta]\[Theta][tt]]Cos[ \[Phi]\[Phi][tt]]
    y=rr[tt] Sin[ \[Theta]\[Theta][tt]] Sin[ \[Phi]\[Phi][tt]]
```

for every set of parameter. Any suggestion to do this? I don't know how to handle the syntax with ParametricNDSolve.

EDIT 1:

The example of the documentation is

```
    model[\[Gamma]_?NumberQ, a_?NumberQ, 
    b_?NumberQ] := (model[\[Gamma], a, b] = 
    First[x /. 
    NDSolve[{x''[t] + \[Gamma] x'[t] + a x[t] + b x[t]^3 == 0, 
    x[0] == 2, x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, 20}]])
```

so the model is given by x that is the result of NDSolve. In my case the result of NDSolve is {r,theta,phi} but I want my model to be defined by {x,y,z} (in general).

Comment: So the data is in `"Cartesian"` coordinate, and `ss` in in `"Spherical"` coordinate, right? But where's the `z`?

Comment: yes, I only need the value in the plane x and y so I didn't define z.

Comment: I don't think you can fit the model without defining `z`. There will be infintely many `{r, \[Phi], \[Theta]}` pairs that correspond to the same `{x,y}` pair if `z` is not specified.

Comment: but my data are on a fixed plane, I have only observed  x and y. I fix the plane giving a constant value to theta.

Comment: You should have mentioned this in your question. Then check the document of `CoordinateTransform`.

Comment: I red it, the problem isn't the transformation of coordinate, but the definition of a model to put in FindFit, because in all the documentation I haven't red a similar example.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand what the problem is. Please show us the specific definition of `model`, and a minimal part of  `data`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106785/discussion-between-orion-and-xzczd).